# Picture not showing until sub has finished

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a project in Excel using VBA. I'm getting sheets from other workbooks, which takes a little time. For a userfriendly perspective, I'd like to show a picture saying "Loading" while the application gets the different sheets.
My problem is that the picture doesn't show before the Sub has finished. I've tried troubleshooting this myself.

I've tried running the code to insert the picture in another Sub being called. I've tried adding "DoEvents". I've tried adding an application wait. I've tried "ActiveWindow.SmallScroll" and "Application.Calculate" all without any luck.
I cannot see why the picture wouldn't show when the code is run.

If I add a break point in the code, the picture shows when I'd like it. I'm out of ideas and hope you can help me.

This is a snip of my code:

```
    Sheet1.Activate
    Application.Goto Reference:=Range("a1"), Scroll:=True
    PicLoad = "PicLoad"
    Sheet1.Pictures.Insert(Pictures & PicLoad & ".jpg").Name = PicLoad & "_picture"
    Sheet1.Pictures(PicLoad & "_picture").Width = Application.Width
    Sheet1.Pictures(PicLoad & "_picture").Left = 0
    Sheet1.Pictures(PicLoad & "_picture").Top = 0
    Sheet1.Shapes(PicLoad & "_picture").Line.Visible = msoTrue
    Sheet1.Shapes(PicLoad & "_picture").Line.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
    Sheet1.Shapes(PicLoad & "_picture").Line.Weight = 1

    If ThisWorkbook.Path = requiredPath Then
        Application.Run "Module4.HideCal"
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 'Sletter alle worksheets undtagen nummer 1
            If ws.Index <> 1 Then
                ws.Delete
            End If
        Next
        thisName = ThisWorkbook.Name

        Workbooks.Open (requiredPath & "\" & fileComponents & "*.xl??"), ReadOnly:=True, CorruptLoad:=xlRepairFile  'f?r componenter ind
        fileComponents = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        total = Workbooks(thisName).Worksheets.Count
        Workbooks(fileComponents).Worksheets(1).Copy _
        after:=Workbooks(thisName).Worksheets(total)
        Workbooks(fileComponents).Close 

        *Continues getting worksheets from different workbooks..
```

The Module4.HideCal contains:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Everything works exactly as it should. The only problem is that the picture doesn't show until the sub has finished. I'd like to show it before the If statement.

Best regards

Comment: So when exactly do you call `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`?

Comment: That's called within - Application.Run "Module4.HideCal"

Answer (score 1):

Check your `Application.ScreenUpdating` - if it is `False`, then *you* have told Excel **not** to show this.  You will need to tell Excel to redraw/update the screen!

One method that sometimes forces the screen to redraw is

```
Application.WindowState= Application.WindowState
```

You may, just to be safe, also want to toggle the `Application.ScreenUpdating` around this:

```
Appliction.ScreenUpdating=True
Application.WindowState= Application.WindowState
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Comment: Yes but Application.ScreenUpdating is set to false later in the code (in the IF statement). While debugging I also tried Application.WindowState = Application.WindowState. Also with no luck.